Which tokens exists on Polygon network?
I want my smart contract to accept tokens from different blockchain networks such as bitcoin or ethereum. I know there are wrapped versions of these tokens that works on the Polygon network. Is there a list of token contract addresses that I can check and add to my contract?
PS: I've found a page named "tokens" on Polygonscan but I am not entirely sure these are the correct smart contracts to use. Can someone confirm?  https://polygonscan.com/tokens

The list you found is simply a list of tokens, sorted by their circulating market cap (in dollars). Having a big (and steady) dollar market cap is a good indicator that the token is not a scam token.
But in general, if you know which tokens you want to include, I would search the project's home pages for the contract addresses. I would not trust a listing like that - it can be manipulated.
